# Strings to Char in C++ Issues

Tags: c++, string, char

I have this code:

```
string username;
string node;
string at;
string final;

struct passwd* user_info = getpwnam("mike"); 
struct utsname uts;

uname(&uts);

username = user_info->pw_name;
node = uts.nodename;
at = "@";
final = username + at +node;
i=strlen(final[0]);
char *pp = new char[i];
strcpy(pp,final);

    fputs(pp, stdout);
```

I just want to convert these 3 `strings` in one `char*`. I know my code is totaly wrong but I test a lot of things through google. Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to use [strings::c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)

```
string final;
const char *pp  = final.c_str();
```

If you need to get the string data in a `char*` and not `const char *` then you need to `copy` it as such:

```
std::string final;

//Allocate pointer large enough to hold the string data +  NULL
char *pp = new char[final.size() + 1];

//Use Standard lib algorithm to copy string data to allocated buffer
std::copy(final.begin(), final.end(), pp);

//Null terminate after copying it
pp[final.size()] = '\0'; 

//Make use of the char *


//delete the allocated memory after use, notice delete []
delete []pp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to have a *char. I would concatonate everything in final. If you need a *char you can acchieve this by calling:

```
 final.c_str();
```

If you want to use char. Make sure that you reserve enough memory:

```
 i=final.size()+1; 
 char *pp = new char[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly convert a `string` to a `char*`.

If a `const char*` is suitable, you can use `string::c_str()`.

Otherwise, you need to copy the contents of the string to a pre-allocated char array.